# Client-Thread mysteriously leaves out Java code, thus not answering

Tags: java, optimization, tcp, jit, aot

**Every line of code is executed -> Event -> Important Java code lines skipped**

**#** *Client-Server* **#** *AssumeNoCodeOptimization* **#** *IDE:Processing* *([Processing.org](https://processing.org/) by MIT)*

There is a Thread "ConnectionHandler" that stays in a loop where it either sends or receives data. Before it receives the first data, every line of code is executed. After that, the **program seems to pause** at a System.out.println()!?
Then, when more data arrive, certain lines of Java Code are executed **again**, but the very same System.out.println() - in addition other things - I mentioned before is skipped.

**The very problem is** actually that a method ***sendOutput()*** is **skipped**. This is what really grinds my gears. Please help.

I am programming in an environment called Processing, developed by the MIT. As far as I know it only wraps more Java code arround your code.

Below the following code snippets I will explain why I think that code optimization by JIT or AOT is not the problem (At the end I guess I will be wrong. I hope the opposite because you can not pass System variables to Processing to suppress optimization)

```
  private void runConnectionHandler() {
    final BufferedReader inFromClient = getBufferedReader(socket);
    final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = getDataOutputStream(socket);
    while (true) {   
      getInput(inFromClient);
      sendOutput(dataOutputStream);
      System.out.println("Cycle ends");
    }
  }


  private void getInput(final BufferedReader input) {
    System.out.println("Get");
    try {
      String clientSentence = null;
      if (input.ready()) {
        while ((clientSentence = input.readLine()) != null) {
          inputQueue.add(new GameData(clientSentence));
          System.out.println("Received se: \"" + clientSentence + "\"");
          System.out.println("1");
        }
        System.out.println("2");
      }
      System.out.println("3");
    } 
    catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void sendOutput(final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream) {
    System.out.println("Send");
    while (outputQueue.peek() != null) {
      try {
        String out = outputQueue.poll().toString();
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(out + "\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("Sent \"" + out + "\"");
      } 
      catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

**OUTPUT: Before first data:**

Having no idea about optimization I would think that it should also come to effect here, but it does not?

```
...
Get
3
Send
Cycle ends
...
```

**OUTPUT: First data arrive**

After the "1" the ouput stops. Why is ***System.out.println("2");*** and so on not executed?! Why does it stop?!?!

```
...
Get
3
Send
Cycle ends    
Get
Received se: "SET PLAY MODE"
1
```

**OUTPUT: Manually sent more data**

Gad dayium, I mean where went my ***System.out.println("Get");*** and everything?!

```
...
Get
Received se: "SET PLAY MODE"
1
Received se: "Hey Ho1"
1
```

**OUTPUT: Server shuts down**

When I shut down the other side (Server), every line of code is executed again ?!?! Futhermore neither it stops, nor an execution is thrown (But maybe different issue).

```
...
Get
3
Send
Cycle ends
...
```

Also if my concept is deeply broken I would appreciate a lot of hints.